# What is this number called?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, terminology

Sorry, pretty awful title to describe my question.

Sometimes I like playing around with series expansions for certain functions on Mathematica, and if the function has a singularity at a point $b$, sometimes the little suggestion box will say something like "Series around $ x=b$" and will give me a series expansion around that point. I know this number is special, I don't know why, but sometimes at that series expansion it will have the obvious singularity, like $\dfrac{1}{x-b}$ and then after that a finite number followed by more powers of $x$ with coefficients.

What is that finite number called?

Comment: What number?${}$

Comment: The coefficient of $(x-b)^0$?  Is it the residue?

Comment: I have an example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28s*%28s%2B1%29%29 If you go to where it says Series expansion at s=0, it will give 1/s-1+s+.....i'm talking about the -1 in that series expansion. Its not always -1, and sometimes there is no constant term at a series expansion around a singularity, but is there a name for the constant term in a series expansion for a function around its singularity?

Comment: Don't you mean $(x-b)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: My bad on the description, its not a coefficient on any of the series terms, its a constant number, there is no x multiplying it.

Comment: These are called Laurent series.

Comment: Hey michael i think you're right about that thing, im looking at it and it is the coefficient of that term. Its called residue?

Comment: Hm, yes, the residue is the coefficient of $(x-b)^{-1}$.

Comment: Then no, its not the residue. The number im talking about, for an example, would be the Euler-Mascheroni constant as the second term of the series expansion of the Zeta function around 1.

Comment: I didn't find a name, but i found a resource about Laurent series and skimmed through it and it looks like the name might in that cause i saw series and stuff, thanks big mike for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually called the constant term. See e.g. [mathwords](http://www.mathwords.com/c/constant_term.htm).